# If I add items to a list with a button, how do I use that updated list in another button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have a list, and then add a new string to that list by pressing a button.  Then I want to press another button, and randomly select one the strings from the list and display it.

My current issue is that when I press the second button, it only displays the first string that was declared outside of the button.

Here is the code.  I've put in comments to explain what the issues are.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
import random
import os

test = Tk()

line = ["old"]

def add():
    global line # I want this updated variable with the new list usable in
                # the other widgets
    line + ["new"]

button = Button(test, text="add string", command=add)
button.pack()

label = Label(test, text="null")
label.pack()

def display():
    label ['text'] = random.choice(line) # after pressing add() I want to be
                                         # able to hit this button and have
                                         # it randomly choose one of the
                                         # strings from the list. But what it
                                         # currently does, is just display "old".

display = Button(test, text="display", command=display)
display.pack()

test.mainloop()
```

I just need to know how to update a list within a widget, and make the updated list usable in other widgets.

Comment: `line += ["new"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `line + ["new"]`, use `line.append("new")`.